# Prove of the idempotent property of projector

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, vectors

Consider the projector $P^{b}_{a}=g^{b}_{a}+u_{a}u^{b}$. **u** is a normalized timelike vector, and **g** a generic metric (but we can assume a form -+++). I need to prove that **PP**=**P**.  I am probably having trouble with the contractions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lack of information in your question, but I assume that $g$ is some metric with signature $(-+++)$ and so $u^a u_a = -1$. If this is the case then

$$ {P^a}_b {P^b}_c = ({g^a}_b + u^a u_b)({g^b}_c + u^b u_c) =\\ {g^a}_b {g^b}_c+ u^a u_b {g^b}_c+ {g^a}_b u^b u_c+ u^a u_b u^b u_c = \\{g^a}_c + u^a u_c + u^a u_c - u^a u_c = \\ {g^a}_c + u^au_c = P^a_c$$

Comment: There was no explicit conditions on the metric, but I can assume that kind of metric just by the context of the course. I was struggling with how to express the product of both projectors: an a,b,b,c structure was missing. Thank you!